# primefaces calendar doesn't display when update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, show, updating

I got a problem with the Primefaces calendar.

It is not show in my Application when updated from other side.

Here, the primefaces calendar it's perfect working

```
<p:outputPanel id="calTask">
   <p:calendar id="calendarTask" value="#{taskAddBean.dateEnd}" showOn="button"> 
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
            listener="#{taskAddBean.changeDates}" 
      /> 
   </p:calendar>
</p:outputPanel>
```

but in the next case, the primefaces calendar doesn't display de popup.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{taskAddBean.selectedActType}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{taskAddBean.lstActType}" /> 
   <p:ajax listener="#{taskAddBean.actTypeChanged}" 
           update="calTask" />
</h:selectOneMenu> </div>

<p:outputPanel id="calTask">
   <p:calendar id="calendarTask" value="#{taskAddBean.dateEnd}" showOn="button"> 
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
            listener="#{taskAddBean.changeDates}" 
      /> 
   </p:calendar>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I don't understand what is the razon

Thanks :)

Comment: have you checked that taskAddBean.actTypeChanged() is getting called, and executes without errors, when you change the selected value, in slectOneMenu ?

Comment: Which version primefaces are using?

Comment: Did you try without `p:ajax`?

Comment: I'm using primefaces 4.0

Comment: I probe without ajax and the result is the same

Comment: The problem is when the primefaces calendar is updated from the selectOneMenu, in this line: <p:ajax listener="#{taskAddBean.actTypeChanged}" update="calTask" /> <---- Here is the problem, if update="calTask" is executed, the primeface calendar  don't show de popup. :)